# Error 'Attempt to create two animations for cell' when reordering

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uitableview

I have a UITableView with sections that "collapse" when you tap the section header. When the section collapses, it really just removes the rows from the section. When I try to reorder a cell from another section below the collapsed section into the collapsed section, the app crashes. I get this error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimationForReorderingRow], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UITableViewSupport.m:847

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempt to create two animations for cell'
```

What's strange is that it works fine if I'm moving the cell into a collapsed section from *above* the collapsed section. It only crashes if I move it from *below* the collapsed section.

Here's my code:

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{    
    if ([proposedDestinationIndexPath section] == 0 && [[JRBTaskStore sharedStore] isTodayCollapsed]) 
        [self hideShowToday];
    else if ([proposedDestinationIndexPath section] == 1 && [[JRBTaskStore sharedStore] isTomorrowCollapsed])
        [self hideShowTomorrow];
    else if ([proposedDestinationIndexPath section] == 2 && [[JRBTaskStore sharedStore] isUpcomingCollapsed])
        [self hideShowUpcoming];
    else if ([proposedDestinationIndexPath section] == 3 && [[JRBTaskStore sharedStore] isSomedayCollapsed])
        [self hideShowSomeday];

    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}


-(void)hideShowToday
{
    [self setDayType: TaskDayTypeToday];
    [self hideShowSection: 0 rows: numberOfRowsInToday array: [[JRBTaskStore sharedStore] todayTasks]];
}

-(void)hideShowTomorrow
{
    [self setDayType: TaskDayTypeTomorrow];
    [self hideShowSection: 1 rows: numberOfRowsInTomorrow array: [[JRBTaskStore sharedStore] tomorrowTasks]];
}

-(void)hideShowUpcoming
{
    [self setDayType: TaskDayTypeUpcoming];
    [self hideShowSection: 2 rows: numberOfRowsInUpcoming array: [[JRBTaskStore sharedStore] upcomingTasks]];
}

-(void)hideShowSomeday
{
    [self setDayType: TaskDayTypeSomeday];
    [self hideShowSection: 3 rows: numberOfRowsInSomeday array: [[JRBTaskStore sharedStore] somedayTasks]];
}


-(void)hideShowSection:(int)section rows:(int)numRows array:(NSArray *)array
{    
    if ([array count] > 0 && [[self tableView] numberOfRowsInSection: section] == 0) {
        // Uncollapse the section

        // Create an array of index paths
        NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        int i = [array count];
        for (int x = 0; x < i; x++) {
            NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: x inSection: section];
            [indexPaths addObject: ip];
        }

        if (dayType == TaskDayTypeToday) {
            numberOfRowsInToday = [array count];
            [[JRBTaskStore sharedStore] setIsTodayCollapsed: NO];
        }
        if (dayType == TaskDayTypeTomorrow) {
            numberOfRowsInTomorrow = [array count];
            [[JRBTaskStore sharedStore] setIsTomorrowCollapsed: NO];
        }
        if (dayType == TaskDayTypeUpcoming) {
            numberOfRowsInUpcoming = [array count];
            [[JRBTaskStore sharedStore] setIsUpcomingCollapsed: NO];
        }
        if (dayType == TaskDayTypeSomeday) {
            numberOfRowsInSomeday = [array count];
            [[JRBTaskStore sharedStore] setIsSomedayCollapsed: NO];
        }

        // Getting the error here
        [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths: indexPaths withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    }
    else if ([array count] > 0 && [[self tableView] numberOfRowsInSection: section] > 0) {
        // Collapse the section

        // Find the index paths of the rows and delete them
        NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        int i = [[self tableView] numberOfRowsInSection: section];
        for (int x = 0; x < i; x++) {
            NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: x inSection: section];
            [indexPaths addObject: ip];
        }

        if (dayType == TaskDayTypeToday) {
            numberOfRowsInToday = 0;
            [[JRBTaskStore sharedStore] setIsTodayCollapsed: YES];
        }
        if (dayType == TaskDayTypeTomorrow) {
            numberOfRowsInTomorrow = 0;
            [[JRBTaskStore sharedStore] setIsTomorrowCollapsed: YES];
        }
        if (dayType == TaskDayTypeUpcoming) {
            numberOfRowsInUpcoming = 0;
            [[JRBTaskStore sharedStore] setIsUpcomingCollapsed: YES];
        }
        if (dayType == TaskDayTypeSomeday) {
            numberOfRowsInSomeday = 0;
            [[JRBTaskStore sharedStore] setIsSomedayCollapsed: YES];
        }

        [[self tableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: indexPaths withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

    }
    else if ([array count] == 0) {
        // There's nothing in the section
    } 
}
```